# Is $X_t=X_{t-1}^{\alpha} + \varepsilon_t$ stationary for $\alpha<1$?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, time-series, stationary-processes

Let {$\varepsilon_t$} be iid. Then, we have time series defined by $$X_t=cX_{t-1}^{\alpha} + \varepsilon_t,$$ with $0<\alpha<1$ and $c\in\mathbb{R}$ and let $\varepsilon_t$ be non-negative. Is it strictly stationary?

If we have $\alpha=1$ we obtain classic AR(1) process, where we need $c<1$ for stationarity. For lower $\alpha$ it seems that $X_t$ is "smaller" and should be also stationary, but I have a hard time proving that. Also, do we need then some restriction for $c$ in such case?

Comment: First of all we should ask ourselves if such a process exists at all

Comment: That is correct, but I am not sure how to prove something like that. It should exist though, because there exists AR process which is almost surely larger for every $t$. And it is not periodic or something. But I am not sure what can be used to proving that.

Comment: @Tom are you worried that one has to choose some branch cut when X becomes negative and become complex ? Or why are you worried that such a process should not exist?

Comment: If it helps, we can consider non-negative and "nice" epsilons

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If someone is interested, this problem is actually a special case of nonlinear autoregressive process.

They are defined as $X_t=f(X_{t-1}) + \varepsilon_t$, where some condition for stationarity (even ergodicity...) is:  $f$ is some measurable function satisfying for some  $c\in[0,1)$ and $K>0$ the following:  $\|f(x)\|\leq c\|x\|+K$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{E}|\varepsilon_t|<\infty$. Reference is [here](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/02331888908802217), and some generalization for heavy tailed noise (if we don't want the existence of moment assumption) is [here](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1360/03za00321.pdf).

Answer (score 3):

The answer will depend on your parameters and your choice of noise. I'll give partial answer, using the following reference: [Peigné, Woess, Stochastic  dyamical systems with weak contractivity properties. I. Strong and local contractivity](http://www.lmpt.univ-tours.fr/%7Epeigne/fichiers/part-I.11-09-08.pdf), which contains many helpful other references (Goldie...).

First, I will exclude the value $0$ of the domain, so that $(X_n)$ takes its values in $\mathbb{R}_+^*$. I denote by $x := X_0$, and set:

$$Y_n^{\ln (x)} := \ln (X_n^x),$$.

$$\Psi_\epsilon (y) := \ln(ce^{\alpha y} + \epsilon).$$

Note that $0 \leq \Psi'_\varepsilon \leq \alpha < 1$ for all $\varepsilon$.

Then $Y_{n+1}^y = \Psi_{\epsilon_n} (Y_n^y)$, and $(\Psi_{\epsilon_n})_{n \geq 0}$ is an i.i.d. family of contraction mappings. The sequence $(Y_n)$ is a Stochastic Dynamical System (SDS). In addition, since all the mappings are $\alpha$-contracting, we get $\lim_{n \to + \infty} |Y_n^x-Y_n^y| = 0$ almost surely for all $x$, $y$. Using the terminology of the article, this SDS is *strongly contractive*.

Under another hypothesis, that the SDS be *recurrent*, Theorem 2.13 tells you that, up to multiplication by a constant, there is a unique invariant Radon measure $\nu$, for which the Markov chain $(Y_n)$ is ergodic, and supported exactly on the smallest nonempty closed subset $L$ such that $\mathbb{P} (\Psi_\epsilon (L) \subset L) = 1$. There are further conditions to guarantee that $\nu(L) < +\infty$ (positive recurrence). Which, I think, is more than what you ask for.

Now, let me go back to this recurrence criterion. It asserts that

$$\mathbb{P} (\liminf_{n \to + \infty} |Y_n^y| < +\infty) = 1$$

for one (or, equivalently here, every) $y$. Since the $\Psi_\varepsilon$ are bounded from below by $\ln (\varepsilon)$, only the upper bound is non-trivial. And here, it will depend on the distribution of the noise $\varepsilon$: if it is very (very, very, very) heavy-tailed, I can imagine that the Markov chain $(Y_n)$ is not recurrent. Anyway, let us get a upper bound: for positive $y$,

$$\Psi_\varepsilon(y) \leq \ln (c+\varepsilon) + \alpha y,$$

whence, if $(Y_m^y, \ldots, Y_{n+m}^y)$ are positive,

$$Y_{n+m}^y \leq \alpha^n Y_m^y + \sum_{k = 0}^{n-1} \alpha^k \ln(c+\varepsilon_{n+m-k}).$$

In particular, if $\lim_{n \to + \infty} Y_n^y = +\infty$, then

$$\lim_{n \to + \infty} \sum_{k = 1}^n \alpha^k \ln(c+\varepsilon_{n-k}) = +\infty.$$

But $\sum_{k = 1}^n \alpha^k \ln(c+\varepsilon_{n-k})$ has the same distribution as $\sum_{k = 0}^{n-1} \alpha^k \ln(c+\varepsilon_k)$. In particular, if $\mathbb{E} (\ln(c+\varepsilon)) < +\infty$, then $\sum_{k = 0}^{n-1} \alpha^k \ln(c+\varepsilon_k)$ converges in $\mathbb{L}^1$, so almost surely

$$\liminf_{n \to + \infty} \sum_{k = 1}^n \alpha^k \ln(c+\varepsilon_{n-k}) < +\infty,$$

and the Markov chain is recurrent. Hence, all you need for the existence and uniqueness of an invariant measure is that $\varepsilon >0$ almost surely and $\mathbb{E} (\ln(1+\varepsilon)) < +\infty$.

Comment: Note that I suspect that $\mathbb{E}(\ln(\ln(1+\varepsilon))) < +\infty$ might be sufficient to get recurrence, but I don't have access to many references, and I don't want to promise something false.

Comment: The answer looks awesome! It is a bit difficult for me because I have never encountered SDS, so I have a few questions if you don't mind. 

1- so you basically took fixed $X_0$, and showed that the process will be ergodic wrt some invariant measure independently on $X_0$. This all holds only if $c>0$ right? (at least the upper bound) And should $\epsilon$ be continuous or anything? I am not sure

2-Process being stationary is equivalent to the existence of a unique Radon measure\mu, for which the process is ergodic?

3- I did not understand the $\mu(L)<\infty$ part. Why do I want that?

Comment: 1) I don't know how you would define this process with $c<0$ (then you could get $X_n < 0$, and how would you define $X_n^\alpha$?). 2) No constraint on $\varepsilon$ except for the ones I gave at the end (positivity and a logarithmic moment). You could most likely get some kind of convergence of the law of the process to $\nu$, but that depends on whether $\nu(L)$ is finite or not, and I would need to troll the literature further to find a suitable statement. 3) Well, that's a very important property of the system (positive recurrent or null recurrent?), which would warrant further analysis.

Comment: Sorry if the questions are not very smart from me. I agree with everything, thank you for the answer. One final question concerning 2) though. Generally, under irreducibility assumption, MC is ergodic iff it is positively recurrent. Now, you showed that such SDS is reccurent+contracting, from which it follows that the process exist and is ergodic (right?). Therefore it must imply that it is also positively reccurent (and stationary), and this holds even without the $\nu(L)<\infty$. Or where am I wrong?

Comment: The mistake is that a process can be ergodic without being positively recurrent. For instance, the simple random walk in $\mathbb{Z}$ is ergodic, recurrent but not positively recurrent (it is null recurrent instead). The property of null recurrent processes are more subtle than that of positively recurrent systems, though.

Comment: I see, so I need to also prove the positive recurrency (i.e. here $\nu(L)<\infty$) to finish the proof. And for that I may need some further assumptions

Answer (score 0):

One can see that it is not stationary in the special case that variance of the shock is zero. You have

$$X_1=cX_0^{\alpha}$$

$$X_2=cX_1^{\alpha}=c^{1+\alpha}X_0^{2\alpha}$$

and generally

$$X_t=c^{1+\alpha(t-1)}X_0^{t\alpha}$$

This can converge to different values depending on $X_0$. When $X_0=0$ it stays at zero. However, for example when $\alpha=0.01$, $c=0.99$ and $X_0=0.01$ it converges to $\approx0.99$. Hence it does not have a well-defined unconditional mean. I believe this argument could be generalized to the case with a strictly positive variance.

Comment: Thanks for an answer. I dont understnad one thing though. If we have zero variance then it nessesary means that we have a constant process. This is because no matter what $X_0$ is, then $X_{10000}$ will be veery close to either 0 or 1 (zero if $X_0=0$, one otherwise). But by the same argument, $X_0$ is very close to 0 or 1 depending on $X_{-10000}$. Goint into limit we obtain that the process is either constant 1 or constant 0. The process is constant i.e is stationary.

Comment: On the other note, if there is non-zero ppty that $X_0\neq 0$ (i.e. let us think that epsilons are continous and non-negative for simplicity) then the option "constant 0" has zero probability and if the variance is "small", the entire process will be "close" to 1.

Comment: @AlbertParadek In your example where it converges to either 0 or 1 the process would not be stationary as we could not define the unconditional mean. In order to be weakly stationary the process needs to have well-defined unconditional mean.  Also the unconditional distribution is undefined.

Comment: @AlbertParadek If you repeat the exercise with an actually stationary process like AR(1) you find that it converges to the same value irrespective of the starting value.

Comment: Consider a constant process with value equal to $X_0$ for all t. This process is stationary, is it not? However, the same argument- if $X_0=0$ then it stays at 0, otherwise it converges to suitable value (converges because it stays at that value). How so that it does not have a well-defined mean?

Comment: @AlbertParadek that is an example of a non-stationary process. Please check again the definition of stationarity. The unconditional distribution by definition makes no reference to the starting value.

Comment: Maybe we refer to something else. I meant exactly this time series, such as in example 1 in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stationary_process#Example_1

Comment: Read the definition of stationarity on the same wiki page. It starts Formally, let... represent the cumulative distribution function of the unconditional (i.e., with no reference to any particular starting value) joint distribution of. Please state your formal definition of stationarity.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/122720/discussion-between-albert-paradek-and-fesman).

Comment: I think that your expression for $X_2$, and thus your general case, is wrong. I get $X_2 = c^{1+\alpha} X_0^{\alpha^2}$.

Comment: @D.Thomine There was a typo in the general formula, which I corrected.  It however doesn't affect the answer as I derived the counterexample using the recursive formula.